# problemas para generar calculos phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

buen dia tengo un problema para generar un calculo dinamico en una celda de excel desde php, en el cual necesito que el usuario ingrese una cantidad y la hoja de calculo gestione el calculo automaticamente pero con datos cargados previamente desde php

```html
$file = $fila + 2;

 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I'.$file.':J'.$file)->applyFromArray($estiloTituloColumnas);
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$file, 'Detalle Efectivo en Soles');
 $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex()->mergeCells('I'.($file).':K'.($file));
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('I')->setWidth(10);
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.($file+1),'Cant');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('J')->setWidth(10);
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.($file+1),'Monto S/.');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('K')->setWidth(10);
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.($file+1),'Total');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.($file+2),'0.10');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.($file+3),'0.20');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.($file+4),'0.50');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.($file+5),'1.0');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.($file+6),'2.0');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.($file+7),'5.0');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.($file+8),'10');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.($file+9),'20');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.($file+10),'50');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.($file+11),'100');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.($file+2),'0');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.($file+3),'0');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.($file+4),'0');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.($file+5),'0');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.($file+6),'0');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.($file+7),'0');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.($file+8),'0');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.($file+9),'0');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.($file+10),'0');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.($file+11),'0');
 //$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.($file+2), '=I'.($file+2).'*J'.($file+2));
```

cualquier ayuda o consejo que me pudiesen dar para resolverlo lo agradecería

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que poner para cada valor su calculo correspondiente

> Lo tienes así:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.($file+2),'0.10');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.($file+3),'0.20');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.($file+4),'0.50');
```

> Deberías tenerlo así:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.($file+2),'0.10');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.($file+2), '=I'.($file+2).'*J'.($file+2));
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.($file+3),'0.20');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.($file+3), '=I'.($file+3).'*J'.($file+2));
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.($file+4),'0.50');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.($file+4), '=I'.($file+4).'*J'.($file+2));
```

> Y al final si necesitas la suma de todos los totales:

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.($file+5),'=sum(K'.$file.':K'.($file+4).')');

> Usamos $file+5 para que coloque el total una linea después del último
>   calculo realizado en la columna 'K'

---

> Si proporcionas más datos será mas fácil apoyarte

---

Comment: lo que pasa es que no si es la version de phpexcel, pero no me realiza nigun calculo directo todo debo hacerlo directamente en la base de datos. lo hice como colocas tu pero me arroja el siguiente error: <b>Notice</b>:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Cerberos\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\Worksheet.php</b> on line <b>1117</b><br />

Comment: Para el ejemplo use la versión PHPExcel 1.8.0 de 02/03/2014 con PHP 5.3.28,
no deberías tener problema, si no pones formula cómo te genera el archivo de excel???

Comment: tengo es la version 7.4 de php y me genera el archivo cuando comento la linea que tiene esa formula o haciendo los calculos con la base de datos directamente